# How to make an O(N) algorithm solution?

Tags: arrays, performance, algorithm, big-o

This problem is a practice problem found on Codility, a link can be found here to an example. https://codility.com/public-report-detail/

Problem: We have an array of N integers -- where 0 <= N < 100,000 -- where each integer is between -2,8XX,XXX and +2,8XX,XXX (signed int range). The challenge is to find whether there exists a point, P, where the summation of all array values prior to P are equal to the summation of those after P.

i.e. sum(A[0] to A[P-1]) == sum(A[P+1] to A[N-1])

```
ex. 
A[0] = -1
A[1] =  3
A[2] = -4
A[3] =  5
A[4] =  1
A[5] = -6
A[6] =  2
A[7] =  1
P = 1 is an equilibrium index of this array, because:
A[0] = −1 = A[2] + A[3] + A[4] + A[5] + A[6] + A[7]
P = 3 is an equilibrium index of this array, because:
A[0] + A[1] + A[2] = −2 = A[4] + A[5] + A[6] + A[7]
P = 7 is also an equilibrium index, because:
A[0] + A[1] + A[2] + A[3] + A[4] + A[5] + A[6] = 0
```

The program can quit after the first instance of an acceptable P is found.

There was 30 minutes to complete the challenge, and evidently the expected solution is O(N). I can think of a few O(NlogN) solutions to the problem -- and an O(N) solution involving the summation of the array before removing values one at a time, but this wouldn't work for extreme cases in which every value is of 2,8XX,XXX,XXX.

I'm working in C++ but even pseudo would be great. Suggestions on the proper algorithm to handle this constraint?

Comment: I'm not sure if you didn't accidentally break: *Copyright 2009–2015 by Codility Limited. All Rights Reserved. Unauthorized copying, publication or disclosure prohibited.* Esp. The *disclosure* =/

Comment: @luk32 IANAL, but I think this tiny excerpt would fall under fair use.

Comment: You need 40 bits for the largest possible sum. Just use a type that can handle at least that many bits. Edit: is the range **2,8xx,xxx** or **2,8xx,xxx,xxx** ?

Comment: Is it allowed to use 64 bit signed integers?

Comment: @Barmar I hope so. The problem is interesting. Ummm, I think this is just an example report. The name under the link is the owner of codility, so it's probably just a public preview of what you get when you pay for it. Not 100% sure. I would take care before pasting links with such a line for a public view =). The report itself might have been proteced, i.e. scores, not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A version that works if you can use 64-bit integers: Calculate the cumulative sum of the array, then copy the array and calculate the cumulative sum again from the back.  Then step through both cumulative sums and where the value at a given index is equal in both, you have P.

E.g., your example array becomes

```
-1 2 -2 3 4 -2 0 1
```

and

```
1 2 -1 3 -2 -3 3 1
  *    *         *
```

where the P points have been marked with an asterisk.

If you can't use 64-bit integers outright, then I guess I would make additional arrays for remainders, i.e. manually recreate 64-bit functionality with another signed int array, and require both arrays to match when checking.  I don't think there's anything else you could do under this general approach.

Comment: Except that you can do this in O(1) space, no need to actually store every partial sum.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes you are right.